# jQuery removal of second input value not working

Tags: jquery

I'm at the start of building a comparison page.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input-one" />
  <input type="text" id="input-two" />
  <button type="submit" value="Compare"></button>
</form>

<div id="form-image-display">
  Basket
</div>

<div class="drone" >
<p class="part">H107</p>
</div>
<div class="drone" >
<p class="part">H107D</p>
</div>
<div class="drone" >
<p class="part">H107C</p>
</div>
<div class="drone" >
<p class="part">H107C+</p>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on a grey product box it adds the item to a basket (actually it displays an image and fills out an input field)

When you click on this generated image (as a form of removing from basket) it is supposed to delete the image and clear the corresponding form field.

This seems to work with one item but not the second.

Can anybody explain what I'm missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".drone").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      var partNumber = $(this).find("p").text();

      if ($("#input-one").val().length == 0 ){
      $('input[type=text]#input-one').val(partNumber),

      $("#form-image-display").append('<img id="'+partNumber+'" class="image-in-basket" src="http://www.cmldistribution.co.uk/product/'+partNumber+'/main.jpg" />');
      }
      else if ($("#input-two").val().length == 0 ){
      $('input[type=text]#input-two').val(partNumber),

      $("#form-image-display").append('<img id="'+partNumber+'"         class="image-in-basket" 
src="http://www.cmldistribution.co.uk/product/'+partNumber+'/main.jpg" />');
      }
    });

  $(document).on('click','.image-in-basket', function(){
    var partNumber = $(this).attr('id');

    if (partNumber = $("#input-one").val(partNumber)){
    $('input[type=text]#input-one').val("")
      $(this).remove();   
    }
    else if (partNumber = $("#input-two").val(partNumber)){
    $('input[type=text]#input-two').val("");
      $(this).remove(); 
    }
   });
});
```

Please check out the Codepen http://codepen.io/dangergeek/pen/XXeXBd

Comment: Comparisons are `==` or `===`, not `=`. Ex `if (partNumber = $("#input-one").val(partNumber)){`. You also don't want anything in the `.val()` in that same line in `$("#input-one").val(partNumber)`.

Comment: Semicolons missing and other syntax errors could be part of it, too. `$('input[type=text]#input-two').val(partNumber),` has a comma instead of a semicolon.

Comment: @area28 Ah, thought comma was acceptable when in same 'if'. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparisons are `==` or `===`, not `=`. Ex `if (partNumber = $("#input-one").val(partNumber)){`.

You also don't want anything in the `.val()` in that same line in `$("#input-one").val(partNumber)`.

**[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrLGGZ)**

Comment: Doh! Thanks, dude. I've been staring at the screen too long today.